# How to calculate covariance of independent standard normally distributed RV's?

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance

Lets say I have 3 RV's that are standard normally distributed and independent : x , y and z

Let X = 4*x + 2*y + 3
and let Y = 5*y + 2*z + 4

How can then the Cov(X,Y) be calculated?

This is what I have done so far to solve this problem:
Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] =

E[(4*x + 2*y + 3)(5*y + 2*z + 4)] - E[4*x + 2*y + 3]E[5*y + 2*z + 4] =

E[20xy+8xz+10y2+4yz+16x+23y+6z+12] - E[4*x + 2*y + 3]E[5*y + 2*z + 4] =

20E[xy]+8E[xz]+10E[y]^2+4E[yz]+16E[x]+23E[y]+6E[z]+12 - (4*E[x] + 2*E[y] + 3 * 5*E[y] + 2*E[z] + 4) =

20 * 0 + 8 * 0 + 10*0^2 +4 * 0 + 16 * 0 +23 * 0  +6 * 0 + 12 - (3 * 4) = 0

But that is not the right answer and I can't figure out why.

**UPDATE**:
10 * E[y]^2 must be 10 * E[y^2]. It is known that Var(y) = E[y^2] - E[y]^2 = 1 (because N(0 , 1) )and E[y] = 0 which gives 1 = E[y^2] - 0. Hence E[y^2] = 1.

**FOR THOSE WHO ARE INTERESTED IN THE ANSWER**:

20 * 0 + 8 * 0 + 10 * 1 +4 * 0 + 16 * 0 + 23 * 0  +6 * 0 + 12 - (3 * 4) =

10 + 12 - 12 = 10

Comment: Hint: the covariance is bilinear, and the covariance of independent variables is $0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my question please take a look at it again

Comment: Here is the mistake: on the LHS you should have $E(y^2)$, not $E(y)^2$. Note that here $E(y)=0$ and $E(y^2)=E(y^2)-E(y)^2=V(Y)=1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Aha yes thanks for noticing that. Btw how did you derive this: **E(y^2)=E(y^2)−E(y)^2=V(Y)=1**

Comment: The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) of the variance, and the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) of a standard normal distribution (mean 0, variance 1). Ah, sorry, it's $E(y^2)-E(y)^2=V(y)=1$, no uppercase Y, it was a typo.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Aha ok so this is how I think you derived it (correct me if I am wrong): Var(y) = E(y^2) − E(y)^2 , knowing that Var(y) = 1 for standard distribution gives:  1= E(y^2) − E(y)^2 , also E(y) = 0. Hence  E(y^2) must be 1. Is this right?

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ok finally I understand it, thanks very much for your help!